# Unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am writing a script and then testing it by copying and pasting into the terminal.  This if statement triggers this response `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`

```
if (( $DNSPropTimeElap < 61 )); Then
    sleep $(( 60 - $DNSPropTimeElap ))
fi
```

Comment: Then is in upper case, change it to lower case.

Comment: @soFan wow I am a noob.  If you post an answer I'll upvote and select as corret.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/# is quite good at catching these errors and also gives suggestions when using deprecated syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Then` to `then`. Remember, `bash` is case sensitive.

```
if (( DNSPropTimeElap < 61 )); then
    sleep $(( 60 - $DNSPropTimeElap ));
fi
```

Comment: `$` on variables inside `(())` is not needed

Comment: corrected.Thanks.

Comment: @Inian Using dollar signs on parameters inside `((...))` or `$((...))` can make debugging easier, though. If you forget to assign a value to `DNSPropTimeElap`, then the dollar-sign-free version will silently expand to 0, while the dollar-sign-prefixed version will expand to the empty string and trigger a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner: totally in agreement, point duly-noted